# changes in style.css reset when clean install vaadin-maven project

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

I am using Maven to handle build and dependency management. I recently bugged by very weird issue related to css. I noticed whenever I run

```
mvn clean install
```

on my project, all my changes inside style.css lost ! however changes inside style.scss retained. How can I maintain the changes inside style.css ?

Comment: The css file is generated via the SASS compiler from the different scss files. SO just add your style definitions in the scss files and it's ok.

Comment: Oh Yes... I shifted all of them and it worked !. btw there are few css inside `style.css` which are constant and never get wiped out after clean build. I searched their presence inside `style.scss` but I did not find them. how are they maintained inside `style.css` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stuff in styles.css is compiled by sass compiler from inherited themes (Valo in most recent version) and from your application specific styles.scss. You should consider it as the ".class" file where ".scss" files are your themes ".java" files.

If you want to fall back from the "sass magic" to basic CSS based themes, build the theme once and then remove or comment out the "compile-theme" target from the vaadin-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml. Then the .css file is no more overridden by vaadin maven plugin. If you have created your project using vaadin-application-archetype, there is also probably a maven-clean-plugin configuration that removes existing .css files from VAADIN/themes directory on each "mvn clean" command. Be sure to remove that as well.